# enum, unknown type name when typedefd in separate header

Tags: c, include, typedef

I have what I feel is a very basic issue but for some reason I can't seem to resolve it. I am getting the following errors:

> drivers/cpufreq/AI_gov.h:37:2: error: unknown type name 'phase_state'
>   drivers/cpufreq/AI_gov.h:38:2: error: unknown type name 'phase_state'

now in my file **AI_gov_phases.h** I have the following typdef enum:

```
typedef enum{
    response,
    animation,
    idle,
    load
} phase_state;
```

now in the file that is throwing the error **AI_gov.h** I have:

```
#include "AI_gov_phases.h"

....

struct AI_gov_info{
    struct AI_gov_cur_HW* hardware;

    struct AI_gov_profile* profile;

    phase_state phase;
    phase_state prev_phase;
};
```

typedef enums are definitely one of my weaker areas so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing seems problematic with this code, are you sure that `AI_gov_phases.h` is the correct file (i.e. you are not including the wrong header)?

Comment: I have double checked everything for typos as I have no idea why this code is not working :( @Groo

Comment: Also check that your include guards are correct, e.g. you didn't copy/paste them from another header without changing the name of the define. (If that's it, nowadays you can use `#pragma once` instead on pretty much any compiler and avoid future headaches like this.)

Comment: I have moved the typdef from AI_gov_phases.h to AI_gov.h and now I get the exact same error but from the other file. Any ideas what could cause this? I have checked my include guards, they all seem to be as they should. @Thomas

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/ttencate/681431d36450f5dc8f284d8e287c233b) compiles just fine for me, so your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep looking @Thomas

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I think I am also getting similar error. For now, I use enum phaseState instead of phase_state. my syntax look similar to typedef enum phaseState{...} phase_state; So instead of typedefed name, I uses enum along with its name (instead of anonymous enum)